# how to redirect to email login page based on email address domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a registration page there i am capturing user email address, once the registration is completed user has to activate an account.. this process is working fine.. now what i am looking here is

i would like to give "Go to my Inbox" button  when the user click on this button it should automatically redirect to email login page

ex: when  user enter yahoo email id at the time of registration in the next step it should redirect to yahoo login page..

ex: when  user enter gmail email id at the time of registration in the next step it should redirect to gmail login page..

ex: hotmail
ex: aol...ect

can any one give me some suggestion on this

Comment: Make a hard-coded list (e.g. in your database) that maps common domains to the login URLs of their respective web interfaces. E.g. `*gmail* => https://mail.google.com`.

Comment: You should also consider addresses that don't have web mail, such as private domains. Perhaps if the database query returns nothing, don't display the "Go to my Inbox" button.

Answer (score 2):

When you assume, that the part after the @ is always he domain, where the user can find it's inbox. (like gmail.com, hotmail.com etc) you could do something like that.

```
(function () {
    var mail = "your.aweseome-mail@gmail.com",
        atPos = mail.indexOf("@"),
        hoster = mail.substring(atPos + 1);
    alert('https://' + hoster);
}())​
```

Update:
Better use a hard coded list (as  Uwe Keim proposed above), since the code above will probably only work with most of the free mail services and not with "private" domains.

Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/4GyTg/

I updated the jsfiddle example, so it uses a list of defined services to check if a domain (for logging into web interface) is available.

```
(function () {
    var mail = "your.aweseome-mail@gmail.com",
        services = {
            "gmail.com": "https://gmail.com",
            "hotmail.com": "https://hotmail.com"           
        },
        atPos = mail.indexOf("@"),
        hoster = mail.substring(atPos + 1);

    if (services[hoster]) {
        alert('Go to: ' + services[hoster]);
    } else {
        alert('Nothing to do here');
    }
}())​
```

Comment: So my domain is "@i-am-the-best-dev-ever.com". How could you assume that this is also my web mailer address? If I have any at all? Also, is there always SSL available?

Comment: First of all I think you're absolutely right. If you have your own domain, this will probably not work. This will only work for all those free services. And if they don't offer ssl, I'd switch my mail provider immediately. But, yeah, using a hard coded list might be the better option.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'd tend to do that on the server and not at the client side, because this list could be become a huge one and transmitting it to the user is not necessary and should therefore be avoided in my opinion.